# Quit x11 after Wine is done?

Tags: mac, osx-lion, xorg, wine

Is it possible to make wine quit the X11 layer after all its processes are done?

I'm using Mac OS X 10.7.1 with Wine 1.3.26.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how X is supposed to work on Mac OS, but on Linux X has the "-terminate" argument. Maybe you should try to start your X with -terminate...